# How do I create this image with the specific font and background color with bootstrap and CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I want to recreate this using bootstrap and css, however I'm not too sure on how to approach it. Do I create a jumbotron and resize it to  a square? Or do I create a column?

Here is my code below

```
#rcorners1 {
border-radius: 25px;
background: #73AD21;
padding: 20px; 
width: 200px;
height: 150px;  
}


<div class="container" >
<p id="rcorners1">JAN</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please add any code you have tried so far, so we can help you.

Comment: This is a result of learning Bootstrap instead of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need a div, like you currently have it.

Check out the snippit.  You will have to measure exact font size and font family.  This is a good start.

```css
#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 38px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #77b26d 0%, #ffffff 55%, #ffffff 57%, #77b26d 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #77b26d 0%, #ffffff 55%, #ffffff 57%, #77b26d 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b26d 0%, #ffffff 55%, #ffffff 57%, #77b26d 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#77b26d', endColorstr='#77b26d', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="rcorners1">JAN<br/>2015</p>
</div>
```